# RadTreeList functionality equivalent can this be achieved in Gridview/Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, telerik, treelist

Telerik has a control called RadTreeList.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/treelist/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

However, In our project we are not using Telerik. I wish we did.

I have to represent the number of applications associated with an individual and on click of that application the details related to the application should be made visible. Similar to the one on the Telerik site.

We are using .NET and I have access to the GridView. I need to know how this can be achieved? In our project we are also using Jquery so is there a way that can be used?

Any help and guidance is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To simulate treelist with the MS Grid (if at all possible), you will need lots of custom code attached to it. You may search in codeplex for open source solution in case using the telerik treelist is not a viable option.